# Not include directory in Python 3.6 with virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6

I am creating two virtual environments named as "venv35" and "venv36" for Python 3.5 and 3.6, respectively. The sub-directory "include" is missing in "venv36", thus "Python.h" cannot found at this environment (Python 3.6). Any ideas about it?

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.5 venv35
$ virtualenv -p python3.6 venv36
$ ls -la venv35 venv36
venv35:
total 28
 .
 ..
 bin
 include
 lib
 pip-selfcheck.json
 share

venv36:
total 24
 .
 ..
 bin
 lib
 pip-selfcheck.json
 share
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a virtual environment is created with "venv", we get:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3.6 -m venv py36
$ ls -la py36/
total 32
.
..
bin
include
lib
lib64 -> lib
pip-selfcheck.json
pyvenv.cfg
share
```

The "include" folder is still empty so the solution seems to be the creation of a symbolic link to the original "include" folder location.

```
ln -s /usr/include/python3.6/ py36/include/python3.6
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to install the headers for Python 3.6:

```
sudo apt install python3.6-dev
```

Comment: In case others aren't sure... this step was sufficient for me when I had the same problem with Python.h not being found from a Python 3.7 venv. i.e., I didn't then also need to create a symlink from my venv's include directory to /usr/include/python3.7 (itself a symlink to /usr/include/python3.7m).